# weigh group of features as one with Weka

Tags: classification, weka, svm

I use Weka for building an SVM Classifier which classify some Tweets.

- Some of the features are representable with a single value (for example the number of retweet for a single tweet)
- Some other features are vector with a very high dimensionality (for example a bag of words histogram of 1000 values).

If I model in Weka each value as an Attribute; I fear that the histogram (which I consider as a single feature, but are in effect 1000 attributes), will predominate over the other single-valued features.

Is there in Weka some way in which handle the multiple-value features as a single one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can combine the array of features using the first tab to get only one feature.

In my opinion, if the array of features describes a histogram that can be fitted to a distribution (with high accuracy, be careful !), you can express the array of features as the parameter(s) of the distribution. Similar distributions will have similar initialization parameter(s), so it makes sense. But you have to check if this can be applied to your data.